# How to get final grand total in a program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This program will ask the user for the number of half-dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies s/he has and then compute the total value. The total value of the change is shown both as the total number of cents and then as the separate number of dollars and cents. I want to include a final total that displays after the user is finished; which will display the total of all amounts entered throughout the session(i.e. all loop iterations). So how can I code this?

```
#getCoin function
def getCoin(coinType):
    c = -1
    while c < 0:
        try:
            c = int(input("How many " + coinType + " do you have? "))
            if c < 0:
                print("Coin counts cannot be negative. Please re-enter.")
        except  ValueError:
            print("llegal input. Must be non-negative integer. Re-enter.")
            c = -1
            
    return c

print("Welcome to the Change Calculator")
print()

choice = input ("Do you have any change (y/n)?")
while choice.lower() == "y":
    h = getCoin("Half-Dollars")
    q = getCoin("Quarters")       
    d = getCoin("Dimes")
    n = getCoin("Nickel")
    p = getCoin("Pennies")
    print()

    TotalVal = (h*50) + (q*25) + (d*10) + (n*5) + p
    print("You have " + str(TotalVal) + " cents.")

    dollars = TotalVal // 100   # // is for division but only returns whole num
    cents = TotalVal % 100      # % is for modulos and returns remainder of whole number

    print("Which is " + str(dollars) + " dollars and " + str(cents) + " cents.")

    choice = input("Do you have more change (y/n)? ")

print("Thanks for using the change calculator.")

finalTotal = TotalVal
print("You had a total of" + finalTotal + " cents.")
print("Which is" + str(finalTotalDollars) + " dollars and" + str(finalTotalCents) + " cents.")
```

Comment: Please show sample input, the resulting output, and the output you are expecting. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Comment: Do you mean if user executes this code multiple times, then you want to display so far what's the grand total from starting ? Like storing all the `finalTotal` value ?

Comment: @Shashank yes I rephrased the question in a much better way. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

To make it so when a user wants to play again, you could use an external file to write to and read from using open, read and write, to store user info.

You could use notepad as .txt and write user name, money, and repeat, so login checks and calls the money at the line after the name.